Execute Group in VS Code Notebook - What does it do and how do I use it?
VS Code has the ability to render Python Jupyter Notebooks. At the top of the render window for a notebook file, there are a number of interactive buttons.
These buttons include buttons to add a new code or markdown cell.
They also include buttons labeled Execute Group 1 and Execute Group 2.
On the particular Notebook I am working with, both of these are disabled.

What do these buttons do and how do I use them?
The behaviour I observe is that these buttons are disabled, and remain disabled even if I try and add a cell to one of the groups.

Is this using the "Jupyter" extension supplied by Microsoft? If so, I've never seen those buttons. Which version of the extension are you using?

@MattPitkin Do you have Jupyter Powertoys installed?

Nope, I don't. But looking at that extension now, I see it has those additional buttons that you see.

In the "Jupyter Powertoys" extension to VS Code, in the "Details" (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter-powertoys?tab=readme-ov-file#notebook-run-groups), it explains that you can add cells to an execute group (e.g., Group 1) using the icons in the cell toolbar. After doing this the "Execute Group 1" button should be available. However (after installing the extension myself), the toolbar button doesn't actually seem to work. Maybe this experimental features, isn't actually enabled yet/is broken/just doesn't work for me!
Update
Based on the discussions in this GitHub issue, it appears that the Execute Groups is not working in v0.1.1 of the Jupyter Powertoys extension. The current solution seems to be to roll back to version 0.1.0:

in the VS Code sidebar click on the "Extensions" tab (or use Ctrl + Shift + X)
find and click on "Jupyter PowerToys"
in the open extension window, in the header information click on the down arrow next to the "Uninstall" button to get a drop down menu and click on "Install specific version"
choose v0.1.0
in the header section click "Reload Window"

Now, in a Jupyter notebook opened in VS Code, if you click in a cell and click the "Add Group 1" cell toolbar button, that cell should now show the text "Group 1" in the bottom left corner. The "Execute Group 1" button will still be greyed out until you add at least 2 cells to the group. You can then click "Execute Group 1" and it will run those cells within the group.
As to why it's not working, I expect it's something to do with this change between v0.1.0 and v0.1.1. Specifically, if I manually install the extension and set the:
useCustomMetadata()

function to always return true so that the custom metadata is being set (as was the v0.1.0 functionality), then the Groups work again.

What was the point of this answer? Have you tried it? Does it work? On my system, it doesn't work as described in the documentation for the extension. The whole point of my question is that I am asking why it does not work as intended.

The point of the answer is that it explains what the buttons should do, which was attempting to answer the "What do these buttons do?" part of your question. Your question doesn't state that you know what the buttons are supposed to do, but they just don't work. I suggest adding your voice to this github issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter-powertoys/issues/95 or this one https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter-powertoys/issues/90.

I have updated the question to make it more clear
